# Having trouble understanding the x and y axis in SVM when training and testing data

Tags: python, svm

I wrote some code based on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/manikg/training-svm-classifier-with-hog-features/log) article.

In the code in the article they have created a partition of 80 percent test and 20 percent data

```
#What percentage of data you want to keep for training
percentage = 80
partition = int(len(hog_features)*percentage/100)
```

Later they have created the following variables, the data frame is two dimensions `np` array --- `data_frame[hog_features,labels]`:

```
x_train, x_test = data_frame[:partition,:-1],  data_frame[partition:,:-1]
y_train, y_test = data_frame[:partition,-1:].ravel() , data_frame[partition:,-1:].ravel()

clf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

now what I don't understand is why for the second dimension of the array (the labels) for the x variables they're including everything except the last value and for the y variables the second dimension of the array is just including the last element of the array from what I can understand using array slicing (Maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your questions is simply : that is how training works :

The training set is a matrix in which the last column correspond to the labels and the rest correspond to the samples.

When slicing  the matrix, you have two parts: the first one concerns the rows, the second one concerns the columns.

**ROWS:**

`:partition` means in fact the first 80% rows - this concerns the training set x_train, y_train

`partition:` means the last 20% rows - concerns the test set, x_test and y_test

**COLUMNS:**

`:-1` mean all but the last column - concerns x_train and x_test

`-1:` mean just the last column - concerns y_train and y_test

Therefore, here you get for x_train and x_test everything but the last value. Be careful, in fact you get 80% of the data is for x_train (`:partition`) and 20% is for x_test (`partition:`). Now, for the labels you get only the last column, and 80% of the rows are for y_train while 20% of the rows are for y_test.

One more detail, your x_train and y_train is a 5D array, according to the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.hog).